# Creating an border line style using :before

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate this stylized line border behind my header (see: https://www.vox.com's yellow border behind 'Top Stories'). I understand that it's being created using `:before` but I can't seem to get my header span (projheader_name) to white out some of the border AND I'm getting two of the `:before` elements created for some reason. One gets inserted after div class="container" and the other after `span="projheader_name"`.

```css
#projheader {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#projheader .container {
  background-color: white;
}

#projheader h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.projheader_name {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

#projheader :before {
  border-left: 4px solid #17A2B8;
  border-right: 4px solid #17A2B8;
  border-top: 4px solid #17A2B8;
  content: " ";
  height: 40px;
  left: 6%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6%;
  top: 27%;
}
```

```html
<section id="projheader">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="projheader_name">
          <h3>Landing Page: Sense</h3>
        </span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: remove space before the :before. it should be `#projheader:before`. space have meaning in CSS .. i let you guess what

Answer (score 1):

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid #17A2B8; border-bottom: 0;
}
h3 span {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.7em;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<h3><span>LANDING PAGE</span></h3>
```